# All of my API calls are just repeated code, is it possible to create an API client that uses a Fluent Interface in PHP?

Tags: php, rest, fluent

I'm consuming a SOAP API and every method I create is the same except for a single string, which matches the name of the function, and the arguments. I feel like it's a great candidate for a Fluent interface. How would I go about making this in PHP though? Is there something I can run still if a method name doesn't exist?

```
   public function getFacilityIds() {
        $params = array(
            'sessionKey' => $this->sessionKey
        );
        return $this->client->__soapCall('getFacilityIds', $params);
    }

    public function getFacilityInformation() {
        $params = array(
            'sessionKey' => $this->sessionKey
        );
        return $this->client->__soapCall('getFacilityInformation', $params);
    }
```

I think this will be most of the code (not including the args), but I have no clue what I would name the function to make this work.

```
   public function ??? () {
        $params = array(
            'sessionKey' => $this->sessionKey
        );
        return $this->client->__soapCall(__FUNCTION__, $params);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like __call is the answer I'm looking for. The flaw I've always had with this though is suggestions don't work in IDE's, how can I get code completion to work in VSCode still while using this method to consume APIs?